# How to use a while (true) on RabbitMQ inside a web application

Tags: java, servlets, rabbitmq

In [this](http://www.rabbitmq.com/tutorials/tutorial-one-java.html) example for Java using RabbitMQ and I have see on the receiver you have this code:

```
  QueueingConsumer consumer = new QueueingConsumer(channel);
channel.basicConsume(QUEUE_NAME, true, consumer);

while (true) {
  QueueingConsumer.Delivery delivery = consumer.nextDelivery();
  String message = new String(delivery.getBody());
  System.out.println(" [x] Received '" + message + "'");
}
```

I don't think to use a while (true) inside a servlet could be a good idea, so I wonder if I should use [Servlet With Thread](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0400__Servlet/ServletWithThread.htm) or what other alternatives I have for this.

Answer (score 0):

You might use a command-parser.

```
boolean enough = false;
while (!enough) {
  QueueingConsumer.Delivery delivery = consumer.nextDelivery();
  String message = new String(delivery.getBody());
  System.out.println(" [x] Received '" + message + "'");
  if (message.toLowerCase().equals("exit")) enough = true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no harm in using `while (true) { ... }` in a servlet because the example is simple.
All it does it waits for the next message and then prints it out.

In more complex applications, there is typically a thread dedicated to just reading the messages and a thread pool to process the messages.

```
while (true) {
    QueueingConsumer.Delivery delivery = consumer.nextDelivery();
    String message = new String(delivery.getBody());
    process(message); // performs the processing in another thread
}
```

The reason you another thread is used for processing is to avoid filling up the message buffer while a message is being processed.
If only 1 thread is used for reading from the queue and processing, new messages won't be read until the processing is complete.
This can result in the queue buffer overflowing.

Answer (score 0):

You should not consume messages as part of your webserver, instead rabbitmq messages should be consumed using another process,  a worker daemon, spring has a nice module for that,  see http://docs.spring.io/spring-amqp/reference/html/amqp.html when written correctly it can also manage a thread pool and be completely independent